# system cannot find the path to anaconda

Tags: windows, jupyter-notebook, command-line, anaconda3

I moved the anaconda file into another folder for sorting the disk. now, I am trying to run jupyter notebook from anaconda power shell prompt I am having this error "The system cannot find the path specified." and the "(base)" is also not displaying.

I even tried to place the anaconda file into its earlier place but the issue is still same."conda init
'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."